# Initialize Variables in a Function

Tags: matlab, function, initialization

In a **SCRIPT**, I'm able to initialize variables which is displayed as empty variables in the workspace:

```
mass = [];
speed = [];
velocity = [];
```

BUT when I place these same initialize variables in a **FUNCTION**, MATLAB does not recognize them and does not store them in the workspace.

```
function myvariables()

    mass = [];
    speed = [];
    velocity = [];
```

How can I execute initialize variables in a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*MATLAB doesn't recognize them*? Oh yes, it does!

It's just that those variables are stored in a different *workspace* (not the [main workspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-workspace.html)), which is bound to the scope of your function.

You can output their value to the command prompt to see that they do get initialized. For example, in your function after initializing `mass = []` write `mass` to verify that this variable is indeed initialized like you want.

The official documentation has several nice articles related to your question that you might want to read:

1. [Base and Function Workspaces](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html)
2. [Share Data Between Workspaces](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html)

Comment: in addition; you can put a [`breakpoint`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-182) in the line that contains `mass = [];`. When you execute your function, the debugger will stop and you will have access to the workspace of the function, allowing you to see `mass`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I never knew that there were other workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

Using the output of a function if you really want to see these variables. For example:

```
    function [mass speed velocity] = initVariables()
        mass = [];
        speed = [];
        velocity = [];
    % ...
```

Then you can pass them to other functions, which works as initialization. But your don't really need to do that.

Comment: That is very helpful also.

Answer (score 0):

Use breakpoints and F10 to run your function, you'll see that the variable are initiated in the function workspace (different than your base workspace).